# Programming workflow for projects with long compile time

Tags: c++, boost, workflow

I wonder, is there any programming workflow especially targeting long compile times?

This is a question I actually have had since shortly after I started programming. My programming workflow always was:

1. Make some small changes e.g. max. 10 lines at a time, especially for the debugging process
2. Compile and check for compile time errors and then runtime errors

Of course the first step may not hold true always, especially when adding a new functionality.

The reasoning behind this workflow is the large amount of typos or logic errors, which just gather after a while and may even produce large walls of consequential errors not making any sense. This is why it's in most cases only feasible to try to correct the first 3 or 4 errors of the compiler the next 20 or so messages will most likely vanish together with the corrected ones.

But now I'm beginning to work on projects, which have increasingly compile times. E.g. for one instance I wanted to reduce my development time by using Boost functions. In the end I just reimplemented that needed function in my own library which compiles hundreds of times faster compared to boost, e.g. a matrix inversion. Another project makes extensive use of template meta programming which I came to hate because of the resulting long compile times >1 min. Everything >3s hinders my workflow.

But in the past there were no possibilities to check every typo like a forgotten brace in C++ or some variable letter written in the wrong case. For every program change it was necessary to rewrite a punched card or maybe submit the printed out source code to the central unix server management. So how did they program? Were they all so attentive that they made far less errors than me (dare I say: our generation)?

I'm not really interested in ideas to reduce compile time as there are aplenty (unsatisfactory) ones already (PCH,...), but instead in suggestions about a different workflow or experiences from people also working on large scale projects with long compile times.

Comment: Using an IDE that supports syntax highlighting and intelligence features like syntax checking while you type, may improve your productivity a lot.

Comment: This question is way too broad! You are basically asking how to design and develop large software systems. People usually acquire the necessary skills after years of studying and/or years of professional experience. How can you expect a Stackoverflow answer to explain what takes years to learn?